# Next.js with Nginx proper configuration for serving static files

Tags: nginx, next.js, static, pm2, nginx-location

I want a proper nginx configuration for my next.js project which is a plattform with multiple users and the possibility to post ads. My question is if this block for serving static files is correct

```
    location /_next/static/ {
        alias /var/www/esfaras/.next/static/;
        expires 365d;
        access_log off;
    }
```

Is the expires value good to odd? I am using getstaticprops and no ssr on the pages i count on being "static".

Is there any difference in this proxy pass

```
 location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000; #
      ...
    }
```

or writing the value like this

```
http://localhost:3000
```

?

Can you detect any flaws or optimisation concerns in the full config below

Here is my full nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name esfaras.de  www.esfaras.de;
    return 301 https://www.esfaras.de$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80; 
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name esfaras.de;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/esfaras.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/esfaras.de/privkey.pem;
 return 301 https://www.esfaras.de$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 80;
    server_name www.esfaras.de;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_min_length 256;

    location /_next/static/ {
        alias /var/www/esfaras/.next/static/;
        expires 365d;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000; # Change to 3001 for the second app, but make sure the second Next.js app starts on port 3001.
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # SSL certificate configurations (managed by Certbot)
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.esfaras.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.esfaras.de/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```